# Implementing Lisp's cons in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lisp

I'm trying to translate Lisp code (found in [Abelson/Sussman MIT course](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/video-lectures/))

```
(define (cons a b)
    (lambda (pick)
        (cond ((= pick 1) a)
              ((= pick 2) b))))

(define (car x) (x 1))

(define (cdr x) (x 2))

(car (cons 2 4))
```

to JavaScript ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7n30nLy8/))

```
function cons(a, b){
    return function(x){
        if(x === 1){
            return a;
        }
        else if(x === 2){
            return b;
        }
    }
}

function car(x){
    x(1);
}

function cdr(x){
    x(2);
}

console.log(car(cons(2,4)));
```

The result in JavaScript is `undefined`. I've followed it in debugger and although `cons` and then `car` return desired value, when it comes to console (or alert, or assigning to a variable), the result is always `undefined`.

What is the right way to implement (or use) this in JavaScript? And is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake, I forgot to return:

```
function car(x){
    return x(1);
}

function cdr(x){
    return x(2);
}
```